# Jit компилятор java

Tags: jit, java

Правильно ли я понимаю, что jit начинает работу с вызова интерпретатора java. При этом происходят 2 вещи: jit -код не оптимизируется, не ждет интерпретатора.

Comment: я не знаю, что такое  "jit -код"

Comment: jit-компилятор может посмотреть на сгенерированный машинный код и сделать новую версию.

Comment: а где бы почитать про алгоитмы работы **JIT**- компилятора, интерпретатора. PS jit-код в моем понимании - это байт-код , прошу прощения

Comment: > PS jit-код в моем понимании - это байт-код , прошу прощения

тогда все стает ещё непонятнее. 

> а где бы почитать про алгоитмы работы JIT- компилятора

начните с чтения документации - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@voipp](/users/12796/voipp)](/users/12796/voipp), что Вы имеете в виду, когда пишете *jit-код не ждет интерпретатора*?

(я подразумеваю, что jit-кодом Вы называете JVM byte code)

А вообще, скорее всего принципиально  Вы правильно понимаете суть дела.

--

Сначала байт-код интерпретируется и при этом накапливается некоторая статистика. После нескольких интерпретаций одного и того же фрагмента байт-кода он  заменяется вызовом создаваемых "на лету" машинных команд.

Просто наберите в гугле

```
jit компиляция
```

и начинайте читать.

Обратите внимание на [Динамическая компиляция и измерение производительности - IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp12214/)